# How to get OUTPUT value from stored procedure in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have this stored procedure that inserted record in table and return `IDENTITY` column value by using `Output Inserted.KID` :

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[InsertNode]
(
    @FName nvarchar(50),
    @Lname nvarchar(50),
    @CDesc nvarchar(max),
    @ParentID int
)
as
begin
    insert into Chart (FName , Lname ,CDesc, ParentID ) 
    Output Inserted.KID
    values (@FName, @Lname, @CDesc, @ParentID)
end
```

**C# code :**

```
public void InsertNode(string FName, string LName, string cDesc, int pid)
{
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConStr"].ConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("InsertNode", con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FName", FName);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lname", LName);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CDesc", cDesc);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParentID", pid);
                con.Open();
                Int32 retVal = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
        Response.Write( "ERROR: Unable to save data !!</br>" + Ex.Message);
    }

    Response.Write( "Data Saved Successfully!");
}
```

Is this the correct way and safe?

Now, how to get `OUTPUT` value from stored procedure in asp.net(c#) ?

Comment: You need to use `.ExecuteReader()` (instead of `.ExecuteNonQuery()`) on your `SqlCommand` object since executing this stored procedure now returns a result set

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConStr"].ConnectionString;
string insertStoredProcName = "dbo.InsertNode";

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertStoredProcName, conn))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    -- set up paramters - DO NOT USE AddWithValue !!        
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@FName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = FName;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Lname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = LName;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@CDesc", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = cDesc;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ParentID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = pid;

    conn.Open();

    using(SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            -- read all returned values - if you only ever insert
            -- one row at a time, there will only be one value to read
           int insertedId = rdr.GetInt32(0);
        }

        rdr.Close();
    }

    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: Just curious to know, I thought wrapping the `connection` inside `using` closes and disposes object itself. However you're still make a call to `conn.Close()`

Comment: @Izzy: yes - it does - and I still prefer to be **explicit** about closing. Yes - the `using` block will dispose of the connection and close it in the process - I just use that as a **backup** and not as my main way of closing a connection (and the same applies to the `SqlDataReader`, too) - I use `using` as a safety net only - not the "normal" way of closing a reader or connection

Comment: Ahh right, I get you..You got me worried a little there as I always let the `using` block dispose the connection for me

Answer (score -1):

OUTPUT will break if you decide to add a trigger in table in future. Also if there are multiple inserts, output will return you ID of each newly inserted row.

Alternatively You can use ExecuteScalar if it's a single insert operation.

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[InsertNode]
(
    @FName nvarchar(50),
    @Lname nvarchar(50),
    @CDesc nvarchar(max),
    @ParentID int
)
as
begin
    declare @KID int

    insert into Chart (FName , Lname ,CDesc, ParentID ) 
    values (@FName, @Lname, @CDesc, @ParentID)

    SELECT @KID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
end
```

C#:

```
int KID = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

Comment: If you assign the `SCOPE_IDENTITY` to a local variable - the result set will not be returned to the caller and therefore cannot be read - this is **NOT** going to work! Also: using `ExecuteScalar()` will break if you ever change this to handle **multiple rows** being inserted at once - `OUTPUT` will still work

Comment: @marc_s Original question shows there is only one insert.